# Do I need to uninstall Django 1.3 before installing Django-nonrel?

Tags: django, mongodb, installation, django-nonrel, mongoengine

I want to use multiple databases in my Django project. I currently have Django 1.3 installed and my project uses PostgreSQL.
I want to add an app that uses MongoDB.

As I understand(please correct me if I'm wrong), to support MongoDB, I need Django-nonrel which is a fork that provides support for non-relational databases.

So what do I need to do to get MongoEngine running in my Django project while still keeping support for the Postgre stuff in my project?

Should I just run the setup.py in the Django-nonrel package? Uninstall the official Django 1.3? I'm confused here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using pip, I think it will do it for you automatically because nonrel marks itself as supplying "django".

You are correct that you will need to uninstall django and install django-nonrel if pip doesn't do that automatically.

As for the apps living on the same project, in your database dictionary you just set one db to use postgres and one to use mongo.

If you have any questions we are here at #django-nonrel on freenode irc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and also for the info about your hangout place. I'm gonna have a lot of questions, I think.

Comment: PS: Do all of MongoEngine, django-MongoKit and django-mongodb-engine require Django-nonrel to be installed?

Comment: Working with MongoEngine now. It doesn't require django-nonrel. Think it's only required by django-mongodb-engine.

Comment: Yes. Only django-mongodb-engine requires django-nonrel, the others you mention are other projects.

Answer (score 1):

best thing you can do is installing django non real on virtualenv

http://zcentric.com/2010/09/24/get-django-nonrel-working-with-virtualenv/

this way you can have both working together (don't need to uninstall django first)

Comment: Yeah, I read about that method. But if I install on virtual env, how would that affect my existing project that uses Postgresql? Will I be able to use multiple backends in my project?

Comment: you gonna still have you postgreSQL working with your former "normal" django project. When you install the django nonreal it will use another database... i'm not sure if i get your question well.